# SwiftUI: scale TextField to fit frame

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I want to perfectly fit a `TextField` into it's given frame:

[image]

The green and yellow border here should fit perfectly. The solution below has some chittering during input, the cursor is too big and the font gets blurry if it gets smaller.

```
TextField("", text: .constant("hello here I am"))
.border(.yellow)
.font(.system(size: 10))
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFill()
.border(.orange)
.frame(width: 60, height: 10)
.border(.green)
.position(x: 180, y: 200)
.accentColor(.clear)
```

Any idea how to properly solve this? The frame size should be dynamic.

I'm using this on a zoomable scrollview to manually overlay text on a specific image part (numbers if they didn't get recognised automatically).

Comment: The `TextField` already fits the frame. The text can not fill the textField width with this height

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes it's basically what I want, only it has a bunch of shortcomings (blurry, huge cursor and jitter) and I'm looking for a solution for those. Maybe something with `.scaleEffect` that brings the cursor to it's regular size but also adjusts the width accordingly

Comment: get rid of the `scaledToFill` then

Comment: Removing that sadly doesn't fix any of the issues

Comment: when you remove all modifiers except for `.font(.system(size: 10))`, what doesn't fit your requirements? Because like said above if you don't do anything, the text field already resizes itself to fit the font. So what's the issue then?

Comment: Ah sry I should've been more specific. The frame size should be dynamic. Also changing to a smaller font size leaves the cursor at the same size.